# Flex Slider: How to differentiate between programmatic versus user change

Tags: apache-flex, slider

I am using HSlider to implement a one-thumb slider control. The thumb position is updated by a timer. However, the user can also update the thumb position by either clicking on a position in the slider track, or by dragging the thumb.

Judging by the Flex documentation, I figured all I needed to do was write a handler for the change event. The [docs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/sliderClasses/Slider.html#event:change) say:

> change     Event Event Object Type:
> mx.events.SliderEvent property
> SliderEvent.type =
> mx.events.SliderEvent.CHANGE
>
> Dispatched when the slider changes
> value due to mouse or keyboard
> interaction.

I wrote my code as follows:

```
<mx:HSlider thumbPress="handleThumbPress(event)" change="handleUserChange(event)"
    showTrackHighlight="true" buttonMode="true" useHandCursor="true" minimum="0" 
    maximum="{_max}" snapInterval="1" enabled="true" width="100%" id="mySlider"
    liveDragging="false" showDataTip="true" verticalCenter="0" horizontalCenter="0" 
    trackSkin="{SliderTrack}" trackHighlightSkin="{TrackHighlightConfigurable}"
    sliderThumbClass="{MySliderThumb}" thumbSkin="@Embed('../imgempty.png')"
    dataTipFormatFunction="dataToolTipFormat"/>
```

What I observe is that my change handler, which is only supposed to be invoked in response to user interaction keeps getting invoked whenever my timer sets the value of the slider. The timer code sets the values quite simply as:

```
private function updateValue( newValue : Number ) : void
{
    mySlider.value = newValue;
}
```

Am I making an obvious mistake? Is there a better way to distinguish between user versus programmatic change of Flex Slider?

Thanks.

-Raj

Answer (score 1):

Change event is not fired if you change value programmatically. When you change value of thumb beyond minimum or maximum value of slider the event is fired. Event also gets fired if you change Minimum or maximum of slider. Is this happening in your code ?

Answer (score 0):

You could just put a boolean wrapping when you set the value programmatically:

```
private var inputByUser:Boolean = false;
private function updateValue( newValue : Number ) : void
{
    if (!inputByUser)
        mySlider.value = newValue;
}
```

I don't know your exact code so I couldn't solve it explicitly, but something along those lines is what I'd do.  You'd set that `inputByUser` in your change handler, like so:

```
private function changeHandler() : void
{
    inputByUser = true;
    updateValue(mySlider.value + 10); // however you're doing it
    inputByUser = false;
}
```

Hope that helps,
Lance

Comment: Lance,
That is a good workaround. Don't you think its a bug in HSlider that it calls my change handler for non-programmatic changes?

Thanks for your response.
-Raj

Comment: I can't really tell, try posting all of your code so I could see.  I doubt it's a bug, because any time the value is set on the slider, it's going to dispatch a change event, which will run any event handlers on it.

Comment: Change seems to be called when you change the dataProvider programatically, it may explain this.